# Using python to type into a website

Tags: python

For example, how would I write a program that opens up facebook and posts a status? I'm trying to learn how to use python to duplicate normal user actions.

Comment: What have you tried? The SO Community will be glad to _assist_ you, however we will not write your code for you ^.^

Comment: Also, for that usage, this is a really bad way of doing it - look into Facebook's API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Facebook has an [API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/) you could use (it also has a [module for Python](https://github.com/pythonforfacebook/facebook-sdk/)) – this would be the "right way" for most of the use cases. Though it wouldn't be the same as "normal user actions", Facebook will distinct between a user using a browser to do things and an application using an API.

If you want to automate your software to browse a website, especially AJAX-y one like Facebook, I'd recommend you to look into [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) – it's a browser automation framework that's available for many languages, including Python.

Answer (score 0):

If you looking for "normal user actions", maybe you find this http://facebookbot.rubyforge.org/ useful. it's facebook-bot written in ruby. It's old, but the principles are still the same.